# What's a way to implement backspace working in field in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am try to create tui via ncurses. And I have same problem.
There are two fields:

```
Name
_______

Password
_______
```

How to implement backspace-support in each field ?
And how to use '*' to show each character in password-field ? (Now I use `field_opts_off(field[1], O_PUBLIC);`and it doesn't show characters in password-field, only move cursor).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tutorial for the forms package that I recall.  However, the ncurses test-programs (which are available separately as [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html)) contains a program **`demo_forms`** which does implement deletion by maintaining the edited field contents as a hidden field buffer, and decrementing its length in the case for `REQ_DEL_CHAR`.

Here is a screenshot of the program:

[image]

Regarding the "non-ncurses" suggestion: [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) *is* a curses/ncurses application, and has no particular dependency upon `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

**"Non-ncurses" solution (just for an alternative):**

You can use `dialog` program to perform this task in a very easy way. Just run some linux system commands from C to achieve a nice TUI.

If you want to install it, the package name is `dialog` too.

For a textfield, you can do: `dialog --inputbox <text> <height> <width> [<init>]`
For a password field: `dialog --passwordbox  <text> <height> <width> [<init>]`

For more info: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Bash_display_dialog_boxes